# ansible nested loops with outerloop as dict and inner loop as value of dict items

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have got ansible dict where key is the name and value is integer value. I want my outer loop to be iterating over dict and then inner loop to iterate for the number of times the value is.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug: msg="region {{ item.key }} value {{ item.value }}"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ objs }}"
      - "{{ item.value }}"
  vars:
    objs:
      amrs: 3
      apac: 1
      emea: 2
```

So the output should be

```
region amrs value 1
region amrs value 2
region amrs value 3
region apac value 1
region emea value 1
region emea value 2
```

I would like to know if above can be achieved via ansible. I've also tried `with_nested` but that did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with helper task to generate sequences:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  vars:
    objs:
      amrs: 3
      apac: 1
      emea: 2
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        tmp_list: "{{ tmp_list | default([]) + [dict(name=item.key,seq=lookup('sequence','count='+item.value|string,wantlist=true))] }}"
      with_dict: "{{ objs }}"
    - debug: msg="region {{ item.0.name }} value {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ tmp_list }}"
        - seq
```

Comment: can you explain tmp_list line in details please. it worked

Comment: we loop over original `objs` dict and grow `tmp_list` starting from empty list adding dict elements with `name` set to original dict's key and `seq` - generated sequence (list) with numbers from 1 to original dict's value.

Comment: Fantastic you are a champ mate!